# Why NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle do not use？

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have three Page（**A,B,C**） in my xamarin.forms project.I have a need that **A** push **B**,**B** puch **C**,When **B** push **C**,I want Set **C** page's Back Button'title to be other title.I use the method:

```
CPage cpage = new CPage();
NavicationPage.SetHasBackButton(cpage,true);
NavicationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(cpage,"A Page");
Navication.PushAsync(cpage);
```

But the C Page's BackButton' Title is also "B Page".Why?

[B Page View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxMeu.png)

[C Page View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WQf8.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SetBackButtonTitle method is a bit unintuitive. If you want to set the title for **C Page**, you have to call SetBackButton title on **B Page** (the previous page)

In **B Page** constructor, after InitializeComponent, call SetBackButtonTitle

```
public BPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetBackButtonTitle(this, "Back Title");
}
```

and push the **C Page** normally as you would

```
 Navigation.PushAsync(cpage);
```

this means, any page pushed from **B Page** will have the back button as "**Back Title**"

Answer (score -1):

Change the title for iOS, the title use in any other page or the title is the same as class name. try to change the title of the page, its work for me.